# Know whether a point is above the sea

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation

How do I check whether a point is above the sea or not with python ?

I've already tried to do it with `mpl_toolkits.basemap` (`Basemap.is_land(x, y)`) but I can't install it on windows. Is this library too old and is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: IIRC the only way I could get basemap to work was to install from the binaries found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap). If you're struggling to install libraries on Windows, it's always worth checking to see if they're available on that site, particularly for the scientific stack

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to install a library manually

Comment: Download the one that is appropriate for your version. Go to the Dowloads folder, hold down shift and right click somewhere in the folder --> "open command window here". Then type `pip install the_full_file_name.whl`

Comment: Thank you very much ! You should add your comment as an answer so that I accept it

Comment: Also note that there is a dependency for `basemap` given in the link I posted - `pyproj` - that you will have to download first. I think it would be better for you to go through the process, verify that the method does as you require and then write as an answer of your own, since I'm not sure that downloading binaries really answers your question.

Comment: I get this error `pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform `

Comment: Do you really have Python 3.7 already? Also, are you sure that you have 64bit system?

Comment: No, still Python 3.6.4, and a 64bits system too

Comment: Then why did you download `cp37` version, which is for 3.7? You need `‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`. Also, if you have Python 2 and 3 on the same system, you might need to use `pip3` to install to the correct version of Python.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know cp37 was for Python 3.7

Comment: Still getting the same error... `pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supporter wheel on this platform`

Comment: You will need to investigate this further on your side. Did you try with `pip3` as I suggested?

Comment: I wrote this `pip3 install pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`